# How to convert date format from dd.mm.yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Input  `13.09.2018 (dd.mm.yy)`

Expected format `13/09/2018 (dd/mm/yy)`

How to convert the input date to expected format in javascript?

Comment: There are a lot of answers covering this. Did none of them help you?

Comment: you can refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: if you only want to edit a string instead of a Date-Object you could use replace e.g. '13.09.2018'.replace(/./g, '/');

Comment: @LucaKiebel I have localization added in my asp.net core application. I have a jquery datepicker which displays data according to locale but when I set the selected date to model I got null as output

Comment: Can't you set desired date format in this datepicker? I'm not sure whether it's datepicker you're using, but the one I've found has option [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

Answer (score 3):

**if your object is Date :**

the fast way that you can do this is here , if you don't want use another lib :

```
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
     year: 'numeric',
     month: '2-digit',
     day: '2-digit'
}).replace(/\./g, '/')
```

result is : "11/09/2018"

**and if you have a string , use this regex :**

```
"13.09.2018".replace(/\./g,'/')
```

result is : "13/09/2018"

Comment: "if your object is Date" a quick and dirty solution would be newDate.toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-').reverse().join('/')

Answer (score 2):

Use `date.replace(/\./g, '/')` to globally replace the `dot(.)` with forward slash.

```js
var date = '13.09.2018';
date = date.replace(/\./g, '/');
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = '13.09.2018';
console.log(date.split('.').join("/"));
```

Comment: Innovative, but inefficient. @Ankit's answer is better.

Comment: NOt sure about better as the output same, I like different way ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you think of reuse, create a function to do that for you, but it's not recommended as it's only one line function, but again if you heavily get use of this, you can write something like this:

```
 String.prototype.replaceAll = String.prototype.replaceAll || function(string, replaced) {
   return this.replace(new RegExp(string, 'g'), replaced);
 };
```

and simply use it in your code over and over like below:

```
 var str = "13.09.2018";
 var res = str.replaceAll(".", "/");
```

Comment: This won't work, since it will just replace the first occurrence.

Comment: @TSR  okay sorry i have edited my answer